# how to compare arrya value with single variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am fetching values from a single column of database which are like 4,5,6,7,8 are stored in

```
$sid=$user['std_list'];
```

and i want to compare it with another variable $ctegoryy['id'] which having same values but in different rows 4,5,6,7,8 but in different rows.
and my code of comparission is

```
<?php   while($ctegoryy=mysql_fetch_array($rsultt)) { ?>

            <li style="text-transform: capitalize;">
            <?php if($ctegoryy['id']==$user['std_list']){
                ?>
            <input  name="std_list[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $ctegoryy['id'];?>" checked>
            <?php }
            else {?>
            <input  name="std_list[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $ctegoryy['id'];?>" /><?php
            } echo $ctegoryy['firstname']."&nbsp&nbsp".$ctegoryy['lastname'];?></li>
             <?php }?>
```

Comment: I understood so that $sid = "4,5,6,7,8" and $ctegoryy['id'] = [4,5,6,7,8]. And what do you want to test - that they contain the same and only the same ids or that any id from one is present in other?

Comment: yes any id of one is present in other should <-- that thing i want to checked

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution for your question compare array value to single variable

```
<?php   
$sid=$user['std_list']; 

//from your question its look like you are receiving value in string  4,5,6,7,8. So need to convert in array. If its in array then you can skip following step
$sid = explode(",", $sid);


while($ctegoryy=mysql_fetch_array($rsultt)) { ?>

            <li style="text-transform: capitalize;">
            <?php if( in_array($ctegoryy['id'] , $sid)){ //PHP in built function to check value exist in array
                ?>
            <input  name="std_list[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $ctegoryy['id'];?>" checked>
            <?php }
            else {?>
            <input  name="std_list[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $ctegoryy['id'];?>" /><?php
            } echo $ctegoryy['firstname']."&nbsp&nbsp".$ctegoryy['lastname'];?></li>
             <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you get row value and convert into array

```
<?php
$access=explode(",",$row['std_list']);
if(in_array($ctegoryy['id'],$access)){ $d='t'; } else { $d='f'; }


<input  name="std_list[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $ctegoryy['id'];?>" <?php if($d=="t") { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>/>
```